# OperationalError: Database is locked in Sqlite3 with peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

There is foreign relationship between ExtensionData and DailyData. I read the ID of ExtensionData to input this into DailyData. But I'm greeted with an OperationalError database is locked when I do it like this. How do I avoid that?

```
def create_ext_data(link, nr_users, downloads, rating, nr_reviews):
    """
    """
    db.connect()
    with db.transaction():
        link_to = ExtensionData.get(ExtensionData.link == link).id
        DailyData.create(link_to=link_to, nr_users=nr_users, nr_reviews=nr_reviews,
    downloads=downloads, rating=rating)
    db.close()
```

Comment: Do these classes use the same `db` variable?

Comment: Yes, they do use the same `db` variable.